# css brackets- trouble with spacing

Tags: css, styles, border, padding

I'm trying to wrap css brackets around my h2 headings (and am probably 90% there), but I'm having trouble working out a few minor kinks:

**1.** The spacing on the right side line is way off- it should be brought over to connect with the bracket. How do I adjust this?

and

**2.** There is a weird opacity issue with the orange being visible through the bg.png- why/how do I fix?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sas9F/)

Ideal:
[image: ideal image]

Currently seeing:
[image: current]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, I am not sure if same was your question:

Change the property of `h2` from `text-align: center;` to: `text-align: left;` and set the padding/margin as you wish.

Comment: that certainly helps with the spacing, but I do need the actual text to be centered..

Comment: For that you might want to reduce the width of your H2 ? Try changing it from 420 to 320 px. or h2 {
    width: 54%;

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Changing the width left me with the odd spacing again similar to the "currently seeing" image above. Also, if at all possible, I'd like to leave the width as is as it will affect the styling of the content which my client was very keen on.

Comment: Can you try : background-color: white; in h2 span for your second issue ??? May be this might fix partial backgroud issue.

Comment: So close! I've updated with a new image above to show you what I'm seeing now. Basically, the spacing has been fixed, but now instead of the background of the text matching the rest of the site, it's solid white.

Also, if I change the text-align back to center (per my client), the spacing issue persists. Is there any way around this?

Comment: So instead of backgroud-color: white, you may specify the color which is there in rest of your background. Say backgroud-color: #EEEEEE;

Comment: Right on, thanks for your help! I wonder why repeating bg.png is creating such an issue.. Is there no way, then, to have `text-align: center`? Even with the proper background, changing the alignment gives that weird spacing.

Comment: For aligning text center, I would again recomment to try changing the width property of h2 as width: 360px; text-align: center;   And if you were using %age instead of pixel width, still text-align :center should work.

Comment: hmm.. This is probably where I will need to find a happy medium between what works and what the client wants. Thanks again for your help- much appreciated.